# VSCode: Git changes not highlighted with badges or gutter indicators

Tags: visual-studio-code

Changed lines were not highlighted with gutter indicators near the line number (e.g., orange and green) as normal. The changed/new file was not labeld with a "M" or "U" badge in the file tree (Explorer). The file was displayed as a modified file in the source contral panel though.

Old repositories do not have this issue, but newly cloned repos have this issue.

This issue is the same as the one reported [in this Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/89104), but the solution there did not work for me.